# Rails: How to get Model where "join_table.attrbute = x" joined, but also all the other

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model `Company`, and a join model `Note`, which has `user_id` and `company_id`. Company has_many notes. Note belongs_to user and company. I'm trying to fetch a list of companies together with notes for a user if it has any, but also all the other companies.

Obviously, doing `Company.joins(:notes).where("notes.user_id = 1")` only get me the ones which has notes and not the others. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 4:

```
Company.joins('LEFT JOIN notes ON companies.id = notes.company_id')
```

[Rails 5](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_outer_joins):

```
Company.left_joins(:notes)
```

You need to do a [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).  This will keep all of the records in table1 (companies) even if they do not have anything to join on in table2 (notes).

There are two ways to then filter by user.

1. Add a where clause.  This will need to have the condition for when there are no notes for the company by checking for a NULL user_id.

   ```
   where(notes: {user_id: [@user.id, nil]})
   ```
2. Add the conditional to the outer join. There is no need for the NULL check as the left join will still return any nulls.

   NOTE: The input (`@user.id` in this case) needs to be sanitized or trusted.

   ```
   joins("LEFT JOIN notes ON companies.id = notes.company_id AND notes.user_id = #{@user.id}")
   ```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Fantastic answer.